# Fast coincidence search algorithm?

Tags: performance, algorithm, matlab

A cry for help to all those good at suggesting fast algorithms, specifically search algorithms!

I'm trying to optimise some MATLAB code which looks for 'coincidences' in a list of chronologically ordered times. A 'coincidence' is defined two or more time that occur within a given time window of one another. For example, if we have the following times:

100
150
210
220
380
500
520
610

and I wanted to look for 'coincidences' within 100 of each other then the following would be returned [100 150], [210 220], [500 520]. Note that each time can only ever be included in one coincidence event, so [150 210 220] is not valid as a three-way coincidence because 150 has already been used in [100 150].

My times are sorted chronologically, so my current MATLAB code simply scrolls a 'window' of 100 through the list and pick out those times which 'fall in'. This works, and isn't too slow, but I wondered if there was a more efficient solution which I've missed? Surely there are some clever tricks which can be played here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [`kmeans`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/kmeans.html) might be helpful

Answer (score 2):

Short answer - no. If I understand you "window scrolling" correctly - you are going through the list, picking each element as the lower point and checking its bigger neighbors. If the neighbor falls within the 100 range you add it to the group. If not you close the group and use the neighbor as the new lower point. Since you only go through each element once that way you cannot improve the complexity of your current algorithm, which is already o(n).

Comment: That's true but he still could write a small mex module in C to speed up the computation by maybe 10 times since a for loop in Matlab is still quite slow. (Maybe this could be added to the answer.)

Comment: So, I'd need to write the main loop in C or C++ then link it in?